# undefined type when i turned my code to Object Javascript AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

i don't understand why i get TypeError (this.req is undefined) on line : 
    if (this.req.readyState === 4) {

```
function RequestCORS(url) {
this.url = "http://crossorigin.me/" + url;
this.req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}

RequestCORS.prototype.send = function () {
this.req.open("GET", this.url);
this.req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.req.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.req.status === 200) {
            console.log(this.req.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log("error request");
            //handleError
        }
    }
};
this.req.send();
};

function main() {
var url = "http://www.01net.com/rss/mediaplayer/replay/";
var requete = new RequestCORS(url);

requete.send();
}


window.addEventListener("load", main);
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

`this.req` is undefined because you're making an asynchronous request and by the time your `onreadystatechange` fires `this` doesn't refer to your `RequestCORS` instance anymore.

You could declare a local variable that remains in scope inside the `onreadystatechange` function.

```
var req = this.req;
this.req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState === 4) {
    if (req.status === 200) {
        console.log(req.responseText);
    } else {
        console.log("error request");
        //handleError
    }
  }
};
```

or use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
this.req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.req.readyState === 4) {
    if (this.req.status === 200) {
        console.log(this.req.responseText);
    } else {
        console.log("error request");
        //handleError
    }
  }
}.bind(this);
```

or get rid of `this.req` entirely

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState === 4) {
    if (req.status === 200) {
        console.log(req.responseText);
    } else {
        console.log("error request");
        //handleError
    }
  }
};
```